# How to split and add 4 days to date DATA in {{x.date}}, join and show them in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split

I'm learning to much but I can't find how to add 4 days (+4) to AngularJS response `{{x.date}}`.

How can I learn about split this date DATA for add 4 days to date DATA and join to show them correctly?

`<p>{{x.date}}</p>` shows in HTML as "29/10/1987", for example.

`x.date` is just an ordinary JavaScript `Date` object.

Comment: What type is `x.date` - is this just a standard JavaScript `Date` object?

Comment: Yes, is a standard Javascript object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add days to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date)

Comment: Juan, can you show readers where you are doing the addition presently? You'll need to add some JS code for this.